# Testing OVH API's to buy a domain name

Tags: api, ovh

I'm using OVH API's to order domain names. However, before delivering my API's in production, I would like to tests them. Do you know how could I test the buying part of the API's without really buying a domain name ?
Thanks in advance.

I searched in the OVH documentation and some sites, but i found nothing.